# NGINX access.log not capturing AWS Load Balancer requests in Odoo

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, odoo

I'm encountering an issue with my `NGINX` setup in `Odoo` where the access.log isn't recording requests coming through an `AWS` Load `Balancer`. Strangely, direct requests log fine, but those routed through the load `balancer` don't appear in the access.log.

I've ensured that my `NGINX` configurations for logging are appropriately set up, but it seems requests from the load `balancer` aren't being logged as expected.

Could this be related to the load `balancer`'s IP masking or the way it forwards requests? How can I configure `NGINX` to properly log requests coming through the AWS Load `Balancer` in an `Odoo` environment?

Any insights or guidance on adjusting configurations would be greatly appreciated!

1. Reconfigure NGINX setup.
2. Activate AWS Load Balancer access logs.